# Can't login with created user in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using .net core 2.0 brand new fresh project.  When building out my roles with Identity I am also creating a user.  To create the user I have the following code.

```
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "SuperAdmin", "Admin", "Support", "User" };

        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                //create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 1
                roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }

        // administrator
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "Administrator",
            Email = "something@something.com",
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };
        var i = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);
        if (i == null)
        {
            var adminUser = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Testing1!");
            if (adminUser.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "SuperAdmin");
            }
        }
```

The user creates, but when I try to login with the email and password it says invalid login.

Comment: What method are you using to sign the user in. For example, on the SignInManager, are you using PasswordSignInAsync? What parameters are you using ( model.email, model.xxxxx)?

Comment: If you're using all the defaults, you need to login with `UserName` instead of `Email`.

Comment: When i register a user the normal way i can login with emaol and password

Comment: @BrennanMann this is what im using var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

Comment: @TheDizzle what do you mean in your comment "register a user the normal way"?  Do you have any additional login requirements other than email confirmation ( i.e., two factor, .. )?  Have you drilled down into the signin result? When you debug, do you see the email and password values properly bound to the model?

Comment: I just mean if I register a user through the register page.  Yes i've drilled down and see the proper values being sent.

Comment: I just looked at the source code...      Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,...  Can you try using the username?

Comment: I just realized that as I refreshed your comment.  I saw in the register method that it was setting email and username to the same thing.  I made the switch and it worked.  I had to set username and email to the same.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: That's not correct. Adding solution answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170042/discussion-between-brennan-mann-and-thedizzle).

Comment: @TheDizzle I've added an alternative solution that will attempt to use either the userName or email address to login the user via one of the methods I listed in my initial solution.

Answer (score 5):

For the PasswordSignInAsync method, that you are using...

> await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password,
>   model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

It requires the username and not the email. There is not a method on the `SignInManager` that uses a string `email` as a parameter to signin with a password.

```
    public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

Please see: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs#L297

If you want to use the email address and not the username, please look at using the following:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

Or:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

Your comment:

> The default Identity install uses the username, which it sets as the
>   email when someone registers. Then the values are the same thats why I
>   needed to change the username to the email upon creation. Thank you
>   though for this response. It will help me not have to constantly make
>   sure I'm updating two fields if someone wants to change their login
>   email.

This may be true for default values; however, it does not reflect the actual code and how the login is resolved. The source clearly uses the userName and not the emailAddress to find the user with the signin operation that you are using.

```
   public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return SignInResult.Failed;
        }

        return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
    }
```

Comment: The default Identity install uses the username, which it sets as the email when someone registers.  Then the values are the same thats why I needed to change the username to the email upon creation.

Thank you though for this response.  It will help me not have to constantly make sure I'm updating two fields if someone wants to change their login email.

Comment: @TheDizzle It's important that you understand the entire picture. I added the actual code that you are invoking. The signin method that you are using, uses the username and not the email. It really has nothing to do with the default values.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

This approach uses the `UserManager<T>` to lookup the user via their email or userName and then uses the `SignInManager<T>` to attempt to login the user using the `PasswordSignInAsync` overload method:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

In this example `T is an ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    ....

   /// <summary>
    /// Handle postback from username/password login
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return await ReturnLoginError(model);
            }

            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email) 
                                   ?? await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

            SignInResult signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, isPersistent: true,
                lockoutOnFailure: true);

             ...
      }
```

This will allow you to use either the email address or username to perform the login.

Answer (score -2):

To solve the issue I had to set the username and the email to the same value as I want my users to login via email.

The `PasswordSignInAsync` wants a username not an email so I had to use this instead.

```
// administrator
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = "something@something.com",
        Email = "something@something.com",
        EmailConfirmed = true
    };
```

Comment: This is not correct. The UserName and Email address are not required to be the same values. The user asking the question does not understand the PasswordSignInAsync routine that he or she is using. The routine clearly uses an username and not an emailAddress.  Please see above.  @TheDizzle

Comment: I understand that it wants a username and password. When you start a new project with individual accounts it asks for email and password. It sets the email and username as the email on register. The username field is then disabled and the user can’t change it. I know it asks for a username which is the same value as the email you register with. That’s why my login wouldn’t work because by default it sets an email as a username. Where I was setting it as administrator. If I used administrator I could have logged in. But I wanted it to be the email.

Comment: I know I can change this and I will. Just default is silly.

Comment: Yea I get it.  I'll just assume i'm not explaining myself clear enough. Thanks for the help.